# Effective way to get part of string until token

Tags: python, string

I'm parsing a very big csv (big = tens of gigabytes) file in python and I need only the value of the first column of every line. I wrote this code, wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
delimiter = ','
f = open('big.csv','r')
for line in f:
    pos = line.find(delimiter)
    id = int(line[0:pos])
```

Is there a more effective way to get the part of the string before the first delimiter?

**Edit:** I do know about the CSV module (and I have used it occasionally), but I do not need to load in memory every line of this file - I need the first column. So lets focus on string parsing.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: What is it about this code that you find unsatisfactory? Does it take too long, use too much memory, you object to it on stylistic grounds, etc?

Comment: No, it works fine, I'm just not very confident with python yet.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it. I personally would tweak it stylistically, but that's my personal preference.

Comment: Regarding your edit - why do you think the csv module is all in memory - it's a generator that operates over a stream... that's all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a = '123456'
>>> print a.split('2', 1)[0]
1
>>> print a.split('4', 1)[0]
123
>>>
```

But, if you're dealing with a CSV file, then:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        print int(row[0])
```

And the csv module will handle quoted columns containing quotes etc...

Answer (score 2):

If the first field can't have an escaped delimiter in it such as in your case where the first field is an integer and there are no embed newlines in any field i.e., each row corresponds to exactly one physical line in the file then `csv` module is an overkill and you could use your code from the question or `line.split(',', 1)` as [suggested by @Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705671/4279).

To handle occasional lines that have no delimiter in them you could use [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
with open('big.csv', 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
       first, sep, rest = line.partition(b',')
       if sep: # the line has ',' in it
          process_id(int(first)) # or `yield int(first)`
```

Note: `s.split(',', 1)[0]` silently returns a wrong result (the whole string) if there is no delimiter in the string.

`'rb'` file mode is used to avoid unnecessary end of line manipulation (and implicit decoding to Unicode on Python 3). It is safe to use if the csv file has `'\n'` at the end of each raw i.e., newline is either `'\n'` or `'\r\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Personnally , I would do with generators:

```
from itertools import imap
import csv

def int_of_0(x):
    return(int(x[0]))

def obtain(filepath, treat):
    with open(filepath,'rb') as f:
        for i in imap(treat,csv.reader(f)):
            yield i

for x in obtain('essai.txt', int_of_0):
    # instructions
```